# linker not finding shared lapack and blas, but I am pointing right to it

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, lapack, blas, rocky-os

I am trying to build a .so that dynamically links against lapack and blas at runtime.  When building, the linker complains that it cannot find lapack and blas, but I am pointing right to them (I think).  What else might I be missing?

I am on a Rocky 9 Linux system (pretty fresh install).  Among other things, I have done `yum install gcc-gfortran lapack-3.9.0-8.el9.x86_64 compat-libgfortran-48-4.8.5-36.5.el9.x86_64 openblas-serial lapack scalapack-common` and also `yum groupinstall "Development tools"`.  Some of these were done to (successfully) get old binaries working again, but I include them in case they might be interfering now.  With `yum list`, I don't see anything else promising to install.

In `/usr/lib64/` I see (among other things):

```
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       18 May 25  2022 liblapack.so.3.9 -> liblapack.so.3.9.0*
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       19 May 25  2022 liblapacke.so.3.9 -> liblapacke.so.3.9.0*
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       19 May 25  2022 liblapacke.so.3 -> liblapacke.so.3.9.0*
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  7496688 May 25  2022 liblapack.so.3.9.0*
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  2908088 May 25  2022 liblapacke.so.3.9.0*
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       18 Jan 18 16:18 liblapack.so.3 -> liblapack.so.3.9.0*
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       22 May 16  2022 libopenblas.so.0 -> libopenblas-r0.3.15.so*
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       23 May 16  2022 libopenblaso.so.0 -> libopenblaso-r0.3.15.so*
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 38111888 May 16  2022 libopenblas-r0.3.15.so*
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 39653512 May 16  2022 libopenblaso-r0.3.15.so*
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       17 May 25  2022 libcblas.so.3.9 -> libcblas.so.3.9.0*
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       16 May 25  2022 libblas.so.3.9 -> libblas.so.3.9.0*
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root   119640 May 25  2022 libcblas.so.3.9.0*
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root   583120 May 25  2022 libblas.so.3.9.0*
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       19 Jun  2  2022 libflexiblas.so.3 -> libflexiblas.so.3.0*
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       24 Jun  2  2022 libflexiblas_mgmt.so.3 -> libflexiblas_mgmt.so.3.0*
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       23 Jun  2  2022 libflexiblas_api.so.3 -> libflexiblas_api.so.3.0*
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  3870704 Jun  2  2022 libflexiblas.so.3.0*
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    53256 Jun  2  2022 libflexiblas_mgmt.so.3.0*
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    15912 Jun  2  2022 libflexiblas_api.so.3.0*
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       17 Jan 18 16:18 libcblas.so.3 -> libcblas.so.3.9.0*
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       16 Jan 18 16:18 libblas.so.3 -> libblas.so.3.9.0*
```

In addition, `whereis liblapack.so` and `whereis libblas.so` both come up empty-handed.

Following what I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424494/linking-a-shared-library-with-another-shared-lib-in-linux), I have done:

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -O -g -fopenmp mylib.c -c -o mylib.pic.o
gcc -shared -fopenmp mylib.pic.o -L/usr/lib64 -lblas -llapack -lm -o mylib.so
```

but I get

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195741/shared-library-problems-on-linux), but it seems wrong that I would have to get into system directories and manually make soft links in order to use standard infrastructure.  There must be a "right" solution I am missing.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am pointing right to them (I think).

No, you are not. You need `libblas.so`, which is not the same as `libblas.so.3`.

The `libblas.so` is needed to link new binaries against `libblas`. The `libblas.so.3` is needed to *run* already linked binaries.

Usually the `.so` libraries are installed as part of `libblas-devel` or a similar package.

Comment: This is the sort of theoretical enlightenment I was looking for, but it only gets me halfway there.  I'm back to "I don't see anything else promising to install."  `yum list | grep blas` only finds (for any architecture, in appstream and epel repos) `blas, flexiblas, flexiblas-netlib, flexiblas-openblas-openmp, openblas, openblas-openmp, openblas-serial, openblas-srpm-macros, clblast, clblast-devel, clblast-tuners, dvblast, liblas, liblas-devel, liblas-tools, openblas-openmp, openblas-serial`. Note that `liblas` is not `libblas`.  Am I stuck, or just to green to know where to look?

Comment: @JackOfAllTrades I know little about what `yum list` produces. You probably want this package: https://rockylinux.pkgs.org/9/rockylinux-crb-x86_64/blas-devel-3.9.0-8.el9.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: Thanks for additional pointer.  Not yet tested installing/linking-against that package.  Accepted because original question ("what am I missing?") is answered.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answer from @EmployedRussian that pointed me in the right direction.  For any other sophomore sys-admins stumbling on this, the rest of the story is that it [seems](https://www.2daygeek.com/comparison-difference-between-dnf-vs-yum/) that `yum` on Fedora systems is being overtaken by `dnf`.  The instructions [here](https://installati.one/rockylinux/8/blas-devel/) are good (also for Rocky 9), and this searchable [site](https://pkgs.org/download/lapack-devel) is very useful for knowing what is available.

Long story short, this fixed my problem:

```
dnf --enablerepo=crb install blas-devel lapack-devel
```